# Why the following python code does not print to file

Tags: python

```
from sys import stdout
stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test'
stdout.close()
```

does create the file, but it contains nothing.

I had to use

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test'
sys.stdout.close()
```

But wouldn't the `from ... import...` automatically make the name available? Why do I still have to use `sys.stdout` instead of `stdout`?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking two questions here? Why your file doesn't contain anything or why you have to use sys.stdout instead of stdout?

Comment: In the second method, you have to use `import sys`.

Comment: This is a very interesting post highlighting the role of `sys.stdout`. However, I think you would benefit a lot from [the logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is this: `print` is equivalent to `sys.stdout.write()`.

So when you do `from sys import stdout`, the variable `stdout` won't be used by `print`.

But when you do

```
import sys
print 'test'
```

it actually writes to `sys.stdout` which is pointing to the `file` you opened.

**Analysis**

```
from sys import stdout
stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test' # calls sys.stdout.write('test'), which print to the terminal
stdout.close()
```

---

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print 'test' # calls sys.stdout.write('test'), which print to the file
sys.stdout.close()
```

**Conclusion**

This works...

```
from sys import stdout
stdout = open('file', 'w')
stdout.write('test')
stdout.close()
```

Comment: It's another question, however, if he really wants to override ``stdout`` just to write something to a file.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer Well said... this becomes relevant if he wants all the `print` statements in a large program to be written to a log file...